# If statements for integer value of string

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring, integer

I need a code that checks if the integer value of a string is between 2 different values.
This is what I tried:

```
-(void)CheckString
{
if ([String intvalue] = > 28.0 && = < 29.0){
Action;
}
```

So I want to check if the intvalue is bigger than 28.0 and is smaller than 29.0.
If the intvalue of the string is between these 2 values, an action starts.
What is the right way / code to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't, in any C-based language, do the compare within bounds like that.  You need to write two separate compare operations, each with it's own two operands.  (You certainly can, however, combine the results of the compares with `&&`.)

Comment: Another good argument for learning C before Objective-C ...

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)CheckString {
    if ([String intValue] = > 28.0 && [String intValue] = < 29.0){
        Action;
   }
}
```

Or:

```
-(void)CheckString {
    int intValue = [String intValue];
    if (intValue = > 28.0 && intValue = < 29.0){
        Action;
   }
}
```

Comment: @MartinR You are correct, sir!  That should be `>=` and `<=`.  Yet another reason for learning C first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)checkString {
    int val = [String intValue];
    if (val >= 28 && val <= 29) { // or use (val == 28 || val == 29)
    }
}
```

And why are you trying to compare the `int` value with the float values `28.0` and `29.0`?

Answer (score 0):

See the comment above - you'll have to do it in two separate comparisons

```
if ([myString intValue] >= 28.0 && [myString intValue] <= 29.0) {
    Action;
}
```

Note: If you're getting the `intValue` of a number, it's impossible for it to be between 28 and 29. So

```
if ([myString intValue] == 28.0 || [myString intValue] == 29.0) {
    Action;
}
```

makes more sense there. If you actually want a decimal, use `[myString floatValue]`.

Comment: Minor point:  "28" is a "decimal" value.  The proper term would be "fraction".